# Drag and drop in IE10, 11

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, drag

I am checking out an example on drag and drop in React and I found really great npm modules in the site. Also I found an example [drag and drop](http://unlockcampus.org/code/tutoring/react-drag-drop-list) which after make a changes like

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.dragged);
```

to

```
e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.dragged.outerHTML);
```

Code is working in Chrome but in IE it's failing. In other browsers I can see dragOver event being fired but in IE10, IE11 dragOver event is not even getting fired and hence 'over' property is not at all being set and throwing an undefined error.

How can I identify where am I going wrong?